# pdf component is missing in com component in .NET

Tags: .net, pdf, com, components

I am creating a form that opens a PDF document for viewing; the PDF component is missing among the options in the COM components; how do I get it?

Comment: What is the name of the assembly that is missing?

Comment: Improved question language.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind. I noticed other components were missing too. I did a complete uninstall and installed again and everything is present.